# unreadable Jupyter Lab Notebook after upgrading pandas (Capture Validation Error)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I was recently using Jupyter lab and decided to update my pandas version from 1.2 to the latest (1.4).  So I ran 'conda update pandas' which seemed to work fine.  However when I then launched Jupyter lab in the usual way 'jupyter lab' and tried to open the workbook I had just been working on I got the below error:

> Unreadable Notebook: C:\Users...\script.ipynb TypeError("**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_validation_error'")

I am getting this same error when trying to open any of my .ipynb files that were previously working fine.  I can also open them fine in jupyter notebook, but for some reason they don't work in Jupyter lab anymore.  Any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Open your notebook up in a text editor and check what value it has listed in the metadata for `nbformat`.  Then check what version of  `nbformat` is installed in your environment (`pip list` etc).

Comment: When I open up the notebook in an editor it  has  "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 5.  The version installed in my environment is nbformat 5.1.3. What should I do next?

Comment: maybe downgrade nbformat to version 4? Or perhaps try a fresh environment. Can't help think there's a dependency mismatch between nbformat and jupyterlab.

Comment: I am having this issue today. Created a fresh environment in Anaconda, installed pandas, matplotlib, scikitlearn, bokeh, seaborn and JupyterLab. Cannot open existing notebooks or create new ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that a recent update to `jupyter_server>=1.15.0` broke compatibility with `nbformat<5.2.0`, but did not update the `conda` recipe correctly per [this Github pull request](https://github.com/conda-forge/jupyter_server-feedstock/pull/84).

It is possible that while updating `pandas`, you may have inadvertently also updated `jupyterlab` and/or `jupyter_server`.

While we wait for the build with the merged PR to come downstream, we can fix this dependency issue by updating `nbformat` manually with

```
conda install -c conda-forge nbformat
```

to get the newest version of `nbformat` with version `>=5.2`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I had installed jupyterlab using conda.

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

and I could not open any notebook (old ones as newly created). What fixed my issue was to uninstall jupyterlab and jupyter and then reinstall jupyter lab.

```
conda remove jupyterlab
conda remove jupyter
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```